# How would I code an embed that gives a random image from a set of images I have the URLs of? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

Here's what it looks like right now. It doesn't work tho, as when I type the command in (.testyi), my bot just comes up with a thin blank embed.

```
async def testyi(ctx):
    items = [
    discord.Embed(image = "thaturlwhatever.jpeg", url = "thaturlwhatever.jpg")
    discord.Embed(image = "thatotherurlwhatever.jpeg", url = "thatotherurlwhatever.jpg")]
    randomitem = random.choice(items)
    await ctx.send(embed=randomitem)
```

Comment: It would be useful if you explain what "doesn't work" exactly.

Comment: Alright, that's now specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
@client.command() 
async def hell(ctx):
    items = ['url_0','url_1','url_2']
    
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.set_image(url=random.choice(items))
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Place all the urls in `items` list then use `random.choice(items)` to get random url!
the `embed.set_image` function has no argument called `name` so we can't use name in this method so i just skipped the name!
and you can't directly add image like this `discord.Embed(image='url')` you need to use `embed.set_image(url='url')` [[set_image: document]](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.set_image)